# How to print all values except for the first element of the first list in a 2d Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, printing, nested-lists

So, for example, if we have the 2D Array:

```
list_2D = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I want it to be able to print out:

```
[[2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

So far, I have tried splicing the list, but I can't figure out a way to isolate just the first element of the first list within the 2D Array.
I feel like the answer lies in list comprehension, but, again, I'm not sure how I would isolate the first element of the first list.
It would be preferrable, if it's possible, if this could fit in just 1 print statement.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun a hack that in one line removes the number, prints, and puts the number back in:

```
list_2D[0][print(list_2D):0] = list_2D[0].pop(0),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyezuCTeyEXBViE62lBHwUhHwThWRyHaREfBVEfBLDaWC6og2iA2uqAoM69EAyqgaWUQC9SFkNYryC/QMNDU@f8fAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can `pop` the value and then print:

```
list_2D = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
list_2D[0].pop(0)
print(list_2D)
```

If you don't want to change the original list, consider copying it and do this on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
print([list_2D[0][1:], *list_2D[1:]])
```

Prints:

```
[[2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```